# Temperature controller with OPC-UA connection

Tags: plc, opc-ua, industrial

I have been trying to find a Temperature Controlller with OPC-UA which supports OPC-UA Comms.

No matter how far I look I have not found any manufacturer making anything like this.

Has any one know of any one making a TC with OPC-UA. Yelp.

Sample TC

```
https://www.ia.omron.com/products/family/3668/feature.html
```

Comment: This is probably the wrong venue for this question. Try an automation forum or /r/PLC.